# SQL Server service can not execute in CentOS

Tags: sql, sql-server, centos, centos7

I want to install SQL Server on [CentOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CentOS).

I initialise this service by the command

```
sudo /opt/mssql/bin/mssql-conf setup
```

When I get the status of the service, I get this error:

> Failed to start Microsoft SQL Server Database Engine

[image]

> /var/opt/mssql/log/

I checked this location to see errors from SQL Server, but this location is empty.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: SQL Server isn't supported on CentOS; I recommend using a supported operating system.

Comment: See [Installation guidance for SQL Server on Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-setup?view=sql-server-ver15) for supported distos.

Comment: @DanGuzman I wonder why, because CentOS is very similar to RHEL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Thom A's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70135088/sql-server-service-can-not-execute-in-centos/77541860#comment123978776_70135088):

> SQL Server isn't supported on CentOS; I recommend using a supported
> operating system.

I tried hard to solve this problem, but I did not find a way and I decided to change my OS.